# How to paste AutoCopy cells into InputForm on Wolfram Cloud?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, inputfiled

I wrote the following document and published it on Wolfram Cloud.

```
DynamicModule[{input = "1+1"},
 Manipulate[
  Column@{InputField[ Dynamic@input, String, ImageSize -> {300, 50}],
    ToExpression[ToString@input]}, AppearanceElements -> None]]
```

https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/c9ee829c-52e4-4eed-b855-54ec0efb340a

On the Cloud page, I AutoCopy the cell represented by StandardForm and pasted it into InputFile. However, the input field was not pasted normally.

[image]

However, cells in the StandardForm format copied from the following web pages are well pasted in the InputForm format.

https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/EulerEquations/

I want to autocopy cells in StandardForm format and paste them in InputForm format. What kind of settings should I set?

Comment: Play around `Boxes` field but StandardForm is not well supported in the Cloud so there will be problems in general. You can't even type a 2D `x^2`. `InputField[Dynamic@input, Boxes, ImageSize -> {300, 50}]`

Comment: Thank you. Thanks to you, I think I will solve the problem well.