# How to get plain text in InputForm format from show expression code?

Tags: showexpression, plaintext

I entered the following code into the Input cell. And the code expressed as RowBox was obtained using the Show Expression menu.

[image]

I want to get a Plain Text in the form of InputForm again from this code.

```
expr = Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{"Plot", "[", 
RowBox[{RowBox[{RowBox[{"Sin", "[", SuperscriptBox["x", "2"], "]"}], "+", 
SqrtBox[FractionBox["x", "2"]]}], ",", RowBox[{"{", RowBox[{"x", ",", "0", ",", "3"}], 
"}"}]}], "]"}]], "Input"]
```

How do I write code to get Plain Text in InputForm format? The text I want to get is as follows.

```
In[1]:= text = ... Code using 'expr' ...
Out[1]= Plot[Sin[x^2] + Sqrt[x/2], {x, 0, 3}]
```

I will continue my next work using the results obtained like this (=text).

Comment: Does this fit your needs [1411](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1411/5478)? So `First[FrontEndExecute[FrontEnd\`ExportPacket[First@NotebookRead[PreviousCell[]],    "PlainText"]]]`

Comment: In fact, the problem I am finally trying to solve is as follows.

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/292526/

Comment: Oh, thank you. I see a clue to the solution! I think I can solve the rest!!

Comment: Eliminating the Cell/BoxData wrappers, you can use ToExpression, e.g., `ToExpression[expr[[1,1]], StandardForm, Defer]`